# logging disabled when used with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, logging, pytest

I am having a problem when using pytest and logging together. When I run a program on its own, I can see its messages printed on screen as well as in the file test.log.

```
python3 main.py -> prints on terminal, and also in test.log
```

However, when I am running the same program with pytest, I am seeing the messages only on screen, but the file test.log is not being created.

```
pytest -vs test -> prints only on terminal, but not in test.log
```

Why is pytest interfering with the logging utility, and what should I do to create these log files when using pytest?

My versions are the following:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
```

The directory structure is the following:

```
├── logger.py
├── main.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_module01.py
```

The code for these files are given below:

```
# logger.py ===================================
import logging

def logconfig(logfile, loglevel):
    print('logconfig: logfile={} loglevel={}..'.format(logfile,loglevel))
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s :: %(message)s')

def logmsg(log_level, msg):
    print(log_level,': ',msg)
    logging.info('INFO: ' + msg)

# main.py =====================================
from datetime import datetime
from logger import *

def main(BASE_DIR):
    LOG_FILE = BASE_DIR + 'test.log'
    logconfig(LOG_FILE,'INFO')
    logmsg('INFO',"Starting PROGRAM@[{}] at {}=".format(BASE_DIR,datetime.now()))
    logmsg('INFO',"Ending PROGRAM at {}=".format(datetime.now()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('./')

# __init__.py =================================
all = ["test_module01"]

# test_module01.py ============================
import pytest
import main

class TestClass01:
    def test_case01(self):
        print("In test_case01()")
        main.main('./test/')
```

Comment: By default, `pytest` captures all log records emitted by your program. This is a feature - this way, if you want to verify your program's logging works as expected, you are not required to actually parse the resulting log file and check what log records were emitted while your test function was running. You simply use the `caplog` fixture and get a list of all log records emitted which is very handy.

Comment: If you want to disable this feature, turn off the `logging` plugin: `pytest -p no:logging` should do the trick.

Comment: @hoefling: "-p no:logging" worked, thanks! Please submit this as an answer, and I will accept. Also please add some details about how to use caplog to get log records if it is turned on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, pytest captures all log records emitted by your program. This means that all logging handlers defined in your code will be replaced with the custom handler `pytest` uses internally; if you pass `-s`, it will print the emitted records to the terminal, otherwise it will print nothing and no further output is being made. The internal handler will capture all records emitted from your code. To access them in the tests, use the [`caplog`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/logging.html#caplog-fixture) fixture. Example: imagine you need to test the following program:

```
import logging
import time


def spam():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)
    logging.debug('spam starts')
    time.sleep(1)
    logging.critical('Oopsie')
    logging.debug('spam ends')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    spam()
```

If you run the program, you'll see the output

```
CRITICAL:root:Oopsie
```

but there's no obvious way to access the debug messages. No problem when using `caplog`:

```
def test_spam(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
        spam()
    assert len(caplog.records) == 3
    assert caplog.records[0].message == 'spam starts'
    assert caplog.records[-1].message == 'spam ends'
```

If you don't need log capturing (for example, when writing system tests with `pytest`), you can turn it off by disabling the `logging` plugin:

```
$ pytest -p no:logging
```

Or persist it in the `pyproject.toml` to not having to enter it each time:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "-p no:logging"
```

The same configuration with (legacy) `pytest.cfg`:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p no:logging
```

Of course, once the log capturing is explicitly disabled, you can't rely on `caplog` anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to persist this configuration in `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: @iamtodor definitely, I have updated the answer with an config snippet example.